# GDAL errors when using Merge in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

Edited to include error messages as text.

I have 3 virtual rasters, each is a 4-band multispectral raster, datatype Float32, with identical CRS and resolution. They have some overlap with each other. I created each virtual raster with the 4 individual bands from each of three drone surveys, with each input file placed into a separate band. I have included a screenshot of the merge command window. [image]
I don't alter any of the advanced parameters. It doesn't make a difference in the errors if I save to temporary file or save to a real file.

When I attempt to merge these rasters, the process fails with the following errors

GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_KEA.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_TileDB.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_HANA.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\li
b\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found.

Each error is actually duplicated in the error log, but I deleted the extras for clarity.

The DLLs definitely exist in the OSGeo4W path where the error states they cannot be found. I haven't found this exact error when googling, but a common theme with these DLL errors may be some sort of PATH misdirect. I have GDAL packages installed in both Anaconda and R, and I'm wondering if that is where the chaos is happening. I have uninstalled and reinstalled OSGeo4W, and using the Advanced Install, installed all packages rather than just the default, just in case there was a dependency issue. If I copy and paste the GDAL/OGR console call shown in the Merge popup and run it directly in the OSGeo4W shell, I get the exact same error strings.

Here are the QGIS details:
QGIS version: 3.28.8-Firenze
QGIS code revision: 5ac45272b58
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.7.0
GEOS version: 3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2
PROJ version: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.5.3 (git-version: 7ec4e6)

Any ideas how I can sort out where the command is going wrong?

Comment: Don't use Merge, use Build Virtual Raster then translate/export the output VRT to your final raster.

Comment: https://mapscaping.com/merging-and-mosaicking-raster-data/

Comment: Is there enough free disk space on your C drive for the temporary rasters? It sounds like GDAL_merge tries to open a file, fails, and then complains when it can't find the file it just tried to create.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Images of error messages are not legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others. Always include error messages in the body of the Question as text.

Comment: You're attracting close votes because you didn't include the error messages as text.  Please edit your question to add them as text.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I don’t have the error logs on a computer at home, so I can’t update the question until I go back to the office.  Should I delete the question until I am able to add the errors as text?

Comment: @user2856 When I try that, the exported geotiff doesn't have the same values as the 3 component rasters, even in locations where there is no overlap and it shouldn't have to interpolate values. E.g. In a non-overlap location, a pixel for Band 3 has a value of 0.0737 in the combined virtual raster, a value of 0.07204 in the component virtual raster, and a value of 0.4256 in the geotiff export of the combined virtual raster.  Any ideas?